# Firestore index URL not generated for arrayContains in collection group?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

`snapshot1` uses and single collection and `snapshot2` uses a collection group

```
final snapshot1 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc('115309562732908784445')
    .collection('user_activities')
    .where('userGroupIDs', arrayContains: 'IIPwobuR3YLrOoLH3TeS')
    .get();
final snapshot2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('user_activities')
    .where('userGroupIDs', arrayContains: 'IIPwobuR3YLrOoLH3TeS')
    .get();
```

`snapshot1` generates fine by `snapshot2` throws

```
Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is 
not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been 
indexed via the Firebase console.)
```

but I'm not getting the auto-generate URL. The above message overlapped the VSCode editor window. I didn't see any URL messages in the Debug Console nor the Firestore logs.

Is there something wrong with my query? Or maybe sometimes you have to create them manually?

Comment: Can you add your edit as an answer?, this can help others

Answer (score 1):

I built the Index manually and it worked fine. Was simple to do following [Todd's blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20do%20this%20manually,collection%20group%22%20scope%2C%20and%20then). As a test, I deleted a couple of my existing Indices and the debugger properly gave me a URL to rebuild. Not sure why it didn't like this one.